# How to allow user inputs in a min-max range in R?

Tags: r

Good afternoon.

My question is very simple.

I'm wanting to retrieve some n user inputs ( a vector of length n ). Only values between 0 and 1 are accepted.

I know how to retrieve values with `scan` function but i don't know how to force users to enter only values in [min-max] interval.

Thank you for help !

Code :

```
x <- scan(,n=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way can be using a `while loop`:

```
stayInLoop <- TRUE
N<-3 # number of elements in vector

while(stayInLoop){
  print("Please insert x") 
  x <- scan(,n=N) #readLines(,n=N)

 if (any(x<0) | any(x>1)) {
    print("Re-enter the values, as valid values can be between 0 and 1") 
    x <- scan(,n=N)
  }

  stayInLoop<-any(x<0) & any(x>1)

}

[1] "Please insert x"
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
Read 3 items
[1] "Re-enter the values, as valid values can be between 0 and 1"
1: 0.2
2: 0.2
3: 0.4
Read 3 items

> x
[1] 0.2 0.2 0.4
```

Comment: Ok ! i thought that there is a built-in option but no problem. Thank you for your precious help !